# Is App Clip required to publish an iOS app to the app store?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

I'm developing a flutter app which is compatible for both Android and iOS. I'm trying to publish my flutter app to app store, but I noticed that in the App Store Connect, there's a section called App Clip. After doing some researches, I feel like my application doesn't really need an App Clip. The problem is, I don't know if it is mandatory or an optional thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not needed

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lazaro, I just looked up once more to make sure that it really isn't needed, and I found this thread which basically answers my question. Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mandatory it is optional.

App Store Connect is confusing for new publishers, do not worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll set this as the correct answer.